# Python Script Less Dependent on Excel Macros

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel, vba

I have a python script that takes two sets of coordinates and compares them to one another and returns the shortest distance between them.

Python handles the heavy lifting, however, python is calling an Excel macro to do the sorting.

My macros sort a column based on distance and then deletes the lines with greater values than the shortest.(the python script compares one item of the first coordinate list to all items in the second list, creating duplicates)

My question is, how can I optimize this and ditch the Excel macros, and have python format the list? The delete line macro takes a significant amount of time to complete.

All files used are .CSV

```
Example(In a temporary file):

set 1 LAT | set 1 LON | set 1 ID | set 2 LAT | set 2 LON | set 2 ID | distance  
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_1,    LON_1,    unique_ID2,   100
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_2,    LON_2,    unique_ID2,   55
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_3,    LON_3,    unique_ID2,   38
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_4,    LON_4,    unique_ID2,   15
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_5,    LON_5,    unique_ID2,   77
```

This is what the data looks like that needs to be sorted. The final output looks like this(In a new file with only the shortest distance values):

```
set 1 LAT | set 1 LON | set 1 ID | set 2 LAT | set 2 LON | set 2 ID | distance  
LAT,      LON,    unique_ID1,    LAT_4,    LON_4,    unique_ID2,   15
```

And then would continue with the next pair of coordinates from set 1.

EDIT: I'm not looking for a complete coded answer, but maybe some module suggestions or examples.

Comment: What type of file is the temporary file?

Comment: As of now, its just a CSV that gets deleted at the end of the script. This 'temp' file is where the macros are run @EFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it fits in memory, which I'd assume it must, since you're using excel, which has a row limit, you can do this pretty easily with the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
df[df['distance'] == df['distance'].min()].to_csv('shortest_only.csv', index=False)
```

To do this without external libraries, you could use the `csv` library, and loop through the rows, keeping those that match the minimum at each

```
import csv

with open('temp.csv', 'r') as file:
    minvalue = None
    rows = []
    header = file.readline()
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        rows.append(line)
        if minvalue:
            minvalue = min(int(line[-1]), minvalue)
            rows = [row for row in rows if int(row[-1]) == minvalue]
        else:
            minvalue = int(line[-1])

with open('shortest_only.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    out.write(header)
    shortest = csv.writer(out)
    shortest.writerows(rows)
```